# Multiple IPs + bridge for KVM

Tags: ip, ip-address, virtualization, kvm

I got a problem at the moment and really don't know where the mistake is. I got a Root-Server from my ISP. This Root-Server has already one IP included and today i booked two more IP-Addresses. So what I want to do now is to map this two new IP-Adresses to two virtual Machines but also hold the included IP for the Root-Server. So how I realize this?

I thought something like:

`br0` - holds the original IP of the Root-Server

`br0:0` - holds first IP of first virtual Machine

`br0:1` - holds second IP of second virtual Machine

But this doesn't work. Any Ideas. I'm really frustrated. Worked the hole Day on it and no solution.

Answer (score 4):

I was also struggling with similar scenario, I've got server and got to point that setting up bridge did cut me out and had to restart to be able to reach it , anyway I've managed to  handle it by iptables ..

```
#create alias for your second ip address (lets say its 111.222.333.2 , local address 192.168.1.2)
ifconfig eth0:1 111.222.333.2 
#you should add netmask to be proper if you've got subnet 

#now you should be able to ping this second address from outside world - try it,
#that is if you have not set up firewall to block pings ... flush iptables rules if you are not sure...

#set up NAT rule (network-address-translate : outside ip-> local ip and back local ip->outside ip)
#assumes your virtual machines lives as 192.168.1.2
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 111.222.333.2 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.2
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.1.2 -j SNAT --to-source 111.222.333.2
```

This did help me with server which has multiple IP addresses and KVM virtual machines,
which were originally run in default network (forward mode=nat), so they had internet through NAT and internal IP at first , this also gives them outside-world public IP address.
You can also do these redirects on port-by-port basis by adjusting iptables rule to set address like -d 111.222.333.2:80 -p tcp and also adding port to local address ...

You may also need to turn on device IP forwarding, you can check that by for example

```
sysctl -a | grep forward
```

(where you should see it on for your eth0 device) , optionally adjusting it by proper sysctl command like

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Map br0 to VM1 and VM2 as TAP DEVICE and in VM1 and VM2 you can see that as eth device;
Assign IP1 and IP2 to VM1 and VM2 respectively; With this configuration you can ping from VM1 to VM2 and from host machine to any guest machine(VM1 or VM2);

The following [link](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/QEMU/Networking) will help you setting up TAP device for VM via bridge; See qemu-ifup script specified there and understand it well.